# Does Flutter Web require additional web server setup (eg. dependencies)?

Tags: flutter, webserver, flutter-web

Does `flutter build web` create self-contained package that is ready to be hosted on any web server or something else is required to be installed (python, nodejs, etc.)?

Comment: `flutter build web` produces you static HTML, JS etc that can be hosted by most web servers - it's just static content. However, your Flutter app running in the browser might want to interact with a back end for APIs etc. Of course, you could use Firebase or similar, or you could write your own, or something else. If taking the middle approach you'll need server-side logic and that's where python, nodejs, etc could be used. Or you could use `shelf` if you'd like to implement your backend in Dart.

Comment: @RichardHeap, Should your comment be an answer?